# Total number of days for a task before going on to the next one, grouped by person

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to show how many days have been worked on a certain task by using the dates in between each “task login” for each person. I think this can be done with one query? I'm open to suggestions and/or ideas.

The Table:

```
--------+-----------+----------
Person  |  TaskLogin |  Date
--------+-----------+----------
Jane    |    A      | 2013-01-01
Jane    |    B      | 2013-01-03
Jane    |    A      | 2013-01-06
Jane    |    B      | 2013-01-10
Bob     |    A      | 2013-01-01
Bob     |    A      | 2013-01-06
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Row 1: Jane starts task A starting 2013-01-01 and works on it until starting Task B on 2013-01-03 = 2 days worked on Task A

Row 2: Jane starts on task B starting 2013-01-03 and works on it until starting task A on 2013-01-06  =  3 days worked on Task B

Row 3: Jane starts on task A starting 2013-01-06 and works on it until starting task B on 2013-01-10  =  4 days worked on Task A

Row 4: Skip because that is the highest date for Jane (Jane may or may not finish task B 2013-01-10 but we will not count it)

Row 5: Bob starts task A starting on 2013-01-01 and works on it until continuing to work on task A by logging it again on 2013-01-06 = 5 days worked on task A

Row 6: Skip because that is the highest date for Bob

A = 11 days because 2 + 4 + 5

B = 3 days because of Row 2

---

The output:

```
------+---------------------
Tasks | Time between Tasks
------+---------------------
A      |   11 days 
B      |   3 days
```

***EDIT:********

The solutions of Nicarus and Gordon Linoff (first pre-2013 solution specifically, with my edits in the comments) works. Note that  (select distinct * from table t) t for table  can be added to Gordon Linoff's solution to accommodate for the case of someone logging in twice in the same day.

Comment: This can in fact be done, but you should attempt it first. :) Share what you've tried and you'll get the help you need.

Comment: You want to substract the dates of task A (and/or B). How do you find the oldest date for task A ? How do you find the earliest? (HINT: order by, count(1), or many better queries). Then, all you want is to find the difference in dates.

Comment: @Fengson, subtracting the oldest date and earliest for a task will not give the full result because they need to be grouped by person and a task needs to be be subtracted by the next taskLogin, not necessarily the same task.

Comment: @Nicarus, Thanks. So far I had the datediff and I was trying to figure out how to get the next date and group it so that it was calculating the date differences between each person and then by taskLogin.

Comment: You could add a sequence, then join on that (sequence = sequence + 1) and use DATEDIFF. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you Nicarus! your idea works very well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `lead()` function.  This is only available in SQL Server 2012.  Before that, the easiest way is a correlated subquery:

```
select TaskLogin, sum(datediff(day, date, nextdate)) as days
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 date
              from table t2
              where t2.person = t.person
              order by date desc
             ) as nextdate
      from table t
     ) t
where nextdate is not null
group by TaskLogin;
```

In SQL Server 2012, it would be:

```
select TaskLogin, sum(datediff(day, date, nextdate)) as days
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (partition by person order by date) as nextdate
      from table t
     ) t
where nextdate is not null
group by TaskLogin;
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately my version is before 2012. It looks like the result of the first query returned 18 days for A and 7 days for B (instead of 11 and 3). However, I think this is the right track, so I will keep working on it! Also, I am not familiar with the t.* and top 1, so I will do some research into those.

Comment: I tweaked your first code to get the desired results. I'll post it below. Thanks again!

Comment: [I can't post an answer for 8 hours, but this is what I ended up using:] select TaskLogin, sum(datediff(day,  theDate, nextDate)) as days
    from (select t.*,
             ( SELECT
        MIN(t2.theDate)
        FROM theLog t2
        WHERE t.theDate < t2.theDate AND t2.person = t.person
             ) as nextDate
      from theLog t
     ) t
    where nextDate is not null
    group by TaskLogin;

Comment: Note: the above code does not account for someone logging in the same task twice in one day, which resultantly doubles the dates in between if the table happens to have that.

Comment: @user3137500 . . and the OP has no indication that that is allowed.  If this is allowed, I would suggest simply using `(select distinct * from table t) t` for `table` in the queries.

Comment: I did not realize that it should be allowed until I ran it with a larger set of data. I'll edit the edit portion in the OP to mention it. That was a simple fix! Thanks again @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but it certainly works:

```
-- Setup table/insert values --
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.#TaskAccounting') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TaskAccounting
END

CREATE TABLE #TaskAccounting
(
Person VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
TaskLogin CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
TaskDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #TaskAccounting
VALUES ('Jane','A','2013-01-01')
INSERT INTO #TaskAccounting
VALUES ('Jane','B','2013-01-03')
INSERT INTO #TaskAccounting
VALUES ('Jane','A','2013-01-06')
INSERT INTO #TaskAccounting
VALUES ('Jane','B','2013-01-10')
INSERT INTO #TaskAccounting
VALUES ('Bob','A','2013-01-01')
INSERT INTO #TaskAccounting
VALUES ('Bob','A','2013-01-06');

-- Use a CTE to add sequence and join on it --
WITH Tasks AS (
SELECT
       Person,
       TaskLogin,
       TaskDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY TaskDate) AS Sequence
FROM
       #TaskAccounting
)

SELECT
       a.TaskLogin AS Tasks,
       CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(DD,a.TaskDate,b.TaskDate)) AS VARCHAR) + ' days' AS TimeBetweenTasks
FROM
       Tasks a
JOIN
       Tasks b
       ON     (a.Person = b.Person)
       AND    (a.Sequence = b.Sequence - 1)
GROUP BY
       a.TaskLogin
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to analyze it, but it looks like it works!